# How do I auto shutdown in kiosk mode instead of sleeping?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, kiosk

I installed Ubuntu in Kiosk mode in a library and I want it to re-start between users. Users always forget to shut down computer. Is it possible to have the computer shut down or reboot automatically,  instead of sleeping or hibernating? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sleepd` command to and `-s` option to modify the action upon inactivity.

Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install sleepd 
sleepd [-s command] -u300
```

Visit [sleepd manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sleepd.8.html) for more info.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! PC sleep's well!!! Can I use that program for shut down PC?

Comment: I found this: http://translate.google.de/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FSkripte%2FAuto_OFF - I try to do it, but it's not work - may be I make mistake somewhere. They has good idea to make autoshutdown. Can you look they script, and try it, if it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Standby/Suspend is a Hardware level state. If you need to implement auto shutdown during standby, you will need to do it in hardware/BIOS level.

Comment: sorry for my english and thanks for comment - I mean users go out but PC works and works. I need a script or program that can shut down PC after 5 or 10 minuts nouse.